# Intuition for the fundamental integral in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, line-integrals

I am reading a lecture note on complex analysis, and the following is in it:

> Let $p\in\mathbb{C}$ and $r>0$. Let $\gamma$ be the curve in $\mathbb{C}$ with parametrization $ z: [0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{C}$ given by
> $$
>     z(t) := p + re^{it}
>     $$
> If $z_0\in B(p,r)$, then
> $$
>     \int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z-z_0}\ dz = 2\pi i.
>     $$
> If $z_0\in \mathbb{C}\setminus\bar{B}(p,r)$, then
> $$
>     \int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z-z_0}\ dz = 0.
>     $$

I understand the proof included, but it did not give me an intuition as to why this is true. Is there any intuition behind this fact? If we think about complex numbers as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $z-z_0$ is the vector from $z_0$ to $z$, so I drew $z-z_0$ as $z$ ranges over $\gamma$. Does this picture explain anything?

[image]

Comment: You can interpret the integral as the “change in argument” of $z - z_0$ as $z$ varies along the curve $\gamma$. See also the definition of “winding number” of a curve.

Comment: since you are using Marshall's book, see pages 65 and 66.  I suggest you spend time on the integration free definition of winding number on page 66 [i.e. normalized sum of the changes in angle over a sufficiently fine partition] to get more intuition.